# Example of a convex function which goes to $0$ at infinity and behaves like $-1/|x|$ in the origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find an example of a real valued function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$ such that:

1. in a neighborhood of the origin it behaves like
   $$g(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|};$$
2. $$\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x)=0;$$
3. it is convex "as $|x|\to\infty$, i.e. it is convex at infinity.

I was thinking thinking to consider exactly $g(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|}$, but I realized that actually it is concave.

Could someone please show me an example of such a function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Such a function does not exist: The graph of a convex function lies above any of its tangents, so that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = -\infty$ is not possible.

Comment: @MartinR and which is at least "convex as $|x|\to\infty$? I edit the question.

Comment: What about $\min(2-1/x, 1/x)$ for $x > 0$ (with small modifications to make it differentable)? You simply “stitch“ two functions with the desired behaviour for $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ together.

Comment: pick your favorite function that satisfies $2,3$ and use a smooth function with compact support to join it with $-1/|x|$ at some point on the positive real axis

Comment: @MartinR thank you for your comment. If I want to move the connecting point to the right? I mean, I would have not exactly (1, 1) but a point further to the right. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln(|x|)}{|x|}$.
Clearly $\lim_{x \to 0}f = -\infty$ so it behaves like $-\frac{1}{|x|}$ near $0$. Also, $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f = \frac{2 \ln \! \left({| x |}\right)-3}{{| x |}^{3}}>0 \implies x\in\left\{\left(-\infty , -{\mathrm e}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right), 
\left({\mathrm e}^{\frac{3}{2}}, \infty \right)\right\}$$
we also have:
$\frac{d}{dx}f = \frac{1-\ln \left({| x |}\right)}{{| x |} x}<0 \implies x\in\{\left(-{\mathrm e}, 0\right), \left({\mathrm e}, \infty \right)\}$. Therefore if $|x| > \mathrm e^{\frac{3}{2}}$, the function becomes convex. Finally, $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f = 0$. Hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Sam, I am going to accept your answer. But do you think your example could be modified in such a way that the first derivative of $f$ is positive (at least briefly) in the part in which it is convex?

Comment: If you want to answer, here is my new question. Thank you in advance. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593163/example-of-a-convex-function-at-infinity-which-goes-to-0-at-infinity-behaves-li

Comment: @C.Bishop, I'd reckon that shouldn't be possible. See if you're starting with a convex function with a positive first derivative at some point $x=a$, then $f$ is momentarily increasing at $x=a$. Eventually you want it to decrease down to 0 though, which means there the function will attain the value $f(a)$ again at some point greater than $a$, say at $x=b$. Now Rolle's theorem tells you that the secant connecting $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(a))$ is actually beneath the function, i.e the function isn't convex.

Comment: @C.Bishop, I think an easier way to see this is as follows: Suppose $f$ is convex for all $x\geq a$ and $D_x(f)(a)>0$, then we need $f'(b)\geq f'(a) > 0$ for all $b>a$. This means the function is strictly increasing over $x\geq a$ which means it can never asymptote to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
  f(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{2}{1+|x|}.
$$
As $x\to 0$, the term $\frac{2}{1+|x|} \to 2$, so $f(x)$ behaves like $-\frac 1 {|x|}$ near $0$. Clearly as $f(x)\to 0$ $|x|\to \infty$. It remains to show that $f(x)$ is convex for $|x|$ large enough. Intuitively, the terms  $-\frac{1}{|x|}$ and $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ approximately cancel each other as $|x|\to \infty$, but the later one, which is convex (on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$) is multiplied by two, so it dominates the other one. For an exact proof, take derivate of $f(x)$ at $x>0$ (the convexity for $x\to-\infty$ follows the fact that the function is even):
$$
  f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{(1+x)^2},
$$
and
$$
  f''(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{4}{(1+x)^3},
$$
which is positive for $x$ large enough.